# Auto-generated custom format ID for InfoPath form text field

Tags: list, infopath, item

May I know how do I use a InfoPath form text field to auto generate a custom format ID?

The custom format ID must be in this format: YYYY/XXXREQ

where YYYY is the year that the item is created, follow by a '/', follow by XXX (a auto-increment value) and REQ is the suffix

Example: When the first item is created on year 2011, it will have the ID 2011/001REQ

So, when the last item created on the same year, assuming it is the 345th item, it will therefore have the ID 2011/345REQ.

As a new year approach, year 2012, the first item created in 2012 will have the ID 2012/001REQ

Answer (score 1):

Add the following nodes on InfoPath with its corresponding formula as default values.
Make sure *Update this value when the result of the formula is recalculated* field is selected on all of them.

Read [Auto-numbering InfoPath forms when they are submitted to a SharePoint form library](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/browserforms/autonumber-infopath-form-submitted-sharepoint-library.htm)

```
nextID = max(@ID) + 1

paddedNextID = concat("000", nextID)
length = string-length(paddedNextID)
startposition = number(length) - 3
properNextID = substring(paddedNextID, startposition + 1, 3)
customID = concat(substring-before(today(), "-"), "/", properNextID, "REQ")
```

Comment: Do I paste the above code to the step 10 of the article : http://www.bizsupportonline.net/browserforms/autonumber-infopath-form-submitted-sharepoint-library.htm? (I tried that and it say that the formula contains one or more errors.)

Comment: Also, how do I reset the ID when a new year approach?

Comment: I've done until step 13.. on step 14 I couldn't find `Rule`. I'm using SharePoint 2013. Please guide.